# ServiceWorker failing to Cache persistent assets

Tags: javascript, caching, progressive-web-apps

I am learning how to implement PWAs and understand the underlying concept thus far. My problem is when I am trying to cache static assets in my service worker file,  nothing is actually being cached and this error is fired instead.

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed`

Below is my code.

````
const staticAssets = [
    './',
    './index.php',
    './account.php',
    './css/account.css',
    './css/bootstrap-4.0.0.css',
    './css/bootstrap.min.css',
    './css/common.css',
    './css/dashboard.css',
    './css/fonts.css',
    './css/home.css',
    './lib/Magnific-Popup/dist/magnific-popup.css', ,
    './lib/sweetalerts/sweetalert.css',

    './images/logo.png',
    './repository/images/*.png',
    './repository/images/*.jpg',
    './repository/images/*.gif',


    './js/account.jsx',
    './js/app.jsx',
    './js/bootstrap-4.0.0.js',
    './js/dashboard.jsx',
    './js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js',
    './js/popper.min.js',
    './js/project.jsx',
    './js/security.jsx',

    './lib/Magnific-Popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
    './lib/Magnific-Popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js',
    './lib/sweetalerts/sweetalert.min.js',
    './lib/sweetalerts/sweetalert.js'
];

self.addEventListener("install",  async event => { 
    const cache = await caches.open("mystatic-assets");
    cache.addAll(staticAssets);
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    const req = event.request;
    event.respondWith(cacheFirst(req));
});

async function cacheFirst(req) { 
    const cacheResponse = await caches.match(req);
    return cacheResponse || fetch(req);
}```


What am I doing wrong?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i have to mention if there is an error or typo in the paths you provide as static URLs it will fail and will not cache anything.

1/ try this

```js
self.addEventListener("install", event => {
    event.waitUntil(
      caches.open("mystatic-assets").then(cache => {
        cache.addAll(staticAssets);
      })
    );
});
```

secondly

in your fetch event

```js
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    const req = event.request;
    event.respondWith(cacheFirst(req));
});

function cacheFirst(req) {
    return chaches.match(req) || fetch(req)
}
```

try this and tell me

Comment: This worked. I also fixed my Paths but it's all working now. Thanx Bruv